# can't create a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to make some changes on a project I'm working on, and one of them is changing some layouts from **RelativeLayout** to **ConstraintLayout**, the thing is that when I replace `"RelativeLayout"` with `"android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout"` or even when I try to create a new XML layout file using `"android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout"` android studio doesn't recognize it at all!!

anyhelp?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you updated your Android Studio to the newest version?

Comment: Yes I updated it a week ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this dependency in `build.gradle` file

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

And If you haven't migrated to gradle 4, use compile instead of implementation.

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Comment: Should I add it to the dependencies section?

Comment: yes. Inside dependencies block. If you haven't migrated to gradle 4, use compile instead of implementation

Comment: I did but the problem remains!

Comment: clean and  rebuild your project

Comment: where? on what line do I add this? EDIT: for some reason, there are 2 build.gradle files, I clicked the wrong one.